# changing the dll's target framework from .NET Framework to .NETCORE

Tags: dll, win-universal-app, uwp, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have the source code of a dll project that Targets .NET Framework. And I'm current developing a Universal App, I want to reference that dll to my project but it is not applicable since the Universal App uses a .NET CORE and that dll is specifically targets .NET Framework.

I'm thinking that I can change the dll's Target Framework since I have the source code but I don't know how.

Or is there another way of solving this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an automated way to convert the library directly (if anyone knows a way, would be more than happy to hear about it).
However, sine you have the source code you can manually move the code.

Create a new Universal Application Class library and start move the code from the old library in there.
Chances are, not everything will work, since there are pretty major differences between namespaces and APIs between .NET framework and .NET core but at least you'll know what you need to change. I would recommend a modular approach where you include portions of the library, make sure it compiles and so on.